# SQL Query optimisation - cast versus converting in ETL

Tags: sql-server, etl, data-warehouse, sql-optimization

I am reviewing some slow running processes in a data warehouse and noticed there are a few cast (column as date) conversion when joining tables in a stored procedure which feeds to the semantic layer.

I was wondering if moving these conversations to the staging layer ETLs will make any noticeable difference?

I understand converting them in the ETL is best practice and you do it only once and don't have use cast on all the other stored procedures/views/queries but I wonder if converting in the ETL is any faster than cast() function in SQL Server?

Comment: Certainly store dates as dates.   Considering the ETL is done once, do it there,

Comment: It seems like you are just guessing and you don't actually know what is causing slowness. Guessing is not the best way to solve a problem. Perhaps the issue lies with the way your queries are structured that use a lazy cast instead of a proper "between" - see [cast is sargable but ...](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea). Maybe you need better indexes?